# Nested JSON items in python Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this JSON python code where I want to get the nested information of currencies and its name. But I have a hard time getting the nested information. Right now I'm getting the list with its dictionary. Do I need to loop currencies and it key values, or is there another way? I have tried with bracket and dot notation, but that haven't worked.

```
[{
"name": "Åland Islands",
"topLevelDomain": [".ax"],
"alpha2Code": "AX",
"alpha3Code": "ALA",
"callingCodes": ["358"],
"capital": "Mariehamn",
"altSpellings": ["AX", "Aaland", "Aland", "Ahvenanmaa"],
"region": "Europe",
"subregion": "Northern Europe",
"population": 28875,
"latlng": [60.116667, 19.9],
"demonym": "Ålandish",
"area": 1580.0,
"gini": null,
"timezones": ["UTC+02:00"],
"borders": [],
"nativeName": "Åland",
"numericCode": "248",
"currencies": [{ "code": "EUR", "name": "Euro", "symbol": "€" }],
"languages": [
  {
    "iso639_1": "sv",
    "iso639_2": "swe",
    "name": "Swedish",
    "nativeName": "svenska"
  }
],
"translations": {
  "de": "Åland",
  "es": "Alandia",
  "fr": "Åland",
  "ja": "オーランド諸島",
  "it": "Isole Aland",
  "br": "Ilhas de Aland",
  "pt": "Ilhas de Aland",
  "nl": "Ålandeilanden",
  "hr": "Ålandski otoci",
  "fa": "جزایر الند"
},
"flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg",
"regionalBlocs": [
  {
    "acronym": "EU",
    "name": "European Union",
    "otherAcronyms": [],
    "otherNames": []
  }
],
"cioc": ""
}]

import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

api_url_base = 'JSON'
resp = requests.get(api_url_base)

js = resp.json()
countries = json_normalize(js)
df = countries[['alpha2Code', 'name', 'region', 'capital', 'population', 
'currencies']]
print(df)
```

My desired output is

```
AX, Åland Island, Europe, Mariehamn, Euro
```

Comment: Can you post your desired outuput?

Comment: @bumblebee My desired output is AX, Åland Island, Europe, Mariehamn, Euro

Comment: Why are you converting the `json` into a `DataFrame`? Instead, you can directly access the data from the `json`.

Comment: @bumblebee Yes I know, but I'm playing around with Pandas that's why I convert it to a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = dict({
"name": "Åland Islands",
"topLevelDomain": [".ax"],
"alpha2Code": "AX",
"alpha3Code": "ALA",
"callingCodes": ["358"],
"capital": "Mariehamn",
"altSpellings": ["AX", "Aaland", "Aland", "Ahvenanmaa"],
"region": "Europe",
"subregion": "Northern Europe",
"population": 28875,
"latlng": [60.116667, 19.9],
"demonym": "Ålandish",
"area": 1580.0,
"gini": 'null',
"timezones": ["UTC+02:00"],
"borders": [],
"nativeName": "Åland",
"numericCode": "248",
"currencies": [{ "code": "EUR", "name": "Euro", "symbol": "€" }],
"languages": [
  {
    "iso639_1": "sv",
    "iso639_2": "swe",
    "name": "Swedish",
    "nativeName": "svenska"
  }
],
"translations": {
  "de": "Åland",
  "es": "Alandia",
  "fr": "Åland",
  "ja": "オーランド諸島",
  "it": "Isole Aland",
  "br": "Ilhas de Aland",
  "pt": "Ilhas de Aland",
  "nl": "Ålandeilanden",
  "hr": "Ålandski otoci",
  "fa": "جزایر الند"
},
"flag": "https://restcountries.eu/data/ala.svg",
"regionalBlocs": [
  {
    "acronym": "EU",
    "name": "European Union",
    "otherAcronyms": [],
    "otherNames": []
  }
],
"cioc": ""
})
print(s['currencies'][0])
```